# Get values in the while loop in real-time

Tags: python

I have a data part which continously generates data in a while-loop. I need to use that values generated under the `data()` to perform further steps like plotting an image.

I first use `"return"` in the `data()` then I found that the value only return once. Then I try to use `yield` in the data part like this.

Here is what my code like:

```
def data():
    while True:
        try:
            navigationStart = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.navigationStart")
            # domComplete = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing.domComplete")
            loadEvent = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.timing. loadEventEnd")
            onloadPerformance = loadEvent - navigationStart
            dtime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            print(dtime, ",", onloadPerformance, "ms")

            yield dtime, onloadPerformance
            driver.refresh()
```

The format of the data part is like:

```
2018-09-07 18:00:20 1100ms
2018-09-07 18:01:10 400ms
......
```

Need to get the values from `data()` to do the following:

```
Class A():
xxxxx
    def test(self):
        self.times, self.Value=zip(*data())
        self.timestamp.append(self.times)
        self.loadingValue.append(self.Value)
```

but it turns out that the times and Value is tuple type. How do I just get append the data one by one with str type instead of tuple?

What I want is like:

```
self.timestamp.append("2018-09-07 18:00:20")
self.timestamp.append("2018-09-07 18:01:10")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question how to get one value out of a tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. As you noticed, `self.times` and `self.Value` are tuples, due to the fact that you're assigning the result of zipping the entire output of `data()` into them. What you want to do is actually simpler: just iterate over `data()` one pair of values at a time:

```
def test(self):
    for times, value in data():
        self.timestamp.append(times)
        self.loadingValue.append(value)
```